# How to calculate months between in hive?

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

Is there a way to calculate months between two dates based on month and year

for eg
`2016-01-01` `2017-01-22`

I need `12` to be returned in integer format in hive.

Answer (score 4):

months_between UDF is available since Hive 1.2.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9518

The manual is here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

months_between takes care about days, not only year and month:

```
hive> select abs(cast(months_between('2016-01-10', '2017-01-10')as int));
OK
12
Time taken: 1.812 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select abs(cast(months_between('2016-01-10', '2017-01-01')as int));
OK
11
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

If you want it to calculate exactly based on month and year, use `trunc()` function:

```
hive> select abs(cast(months_between(trunc('2016-01-10','MM'), trunc('2017-01-01','MM'))as int));
OK
12
Time taken: 0.123 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: I know that but it wont calculate exactly based on month and year which should calculate only months like 12 months not to consider day

Answer (score 0):

May be write your own UDF which will do something like -

1. Covert date(s) to unix time stamps
2. substract higher time stamp from lower
3. result is time duration between two dates
4. divide result by (60 sec * 60 min * 24 hrs * 30 days) to get month

Answer (score 0):

Can you done using following ... with day consideration

```
select (cast(year('2017-01-22') as int) - cast(year('2016-01-01') as int) )*12 +  (cast(month('2017-01-22') as int) - cast(month('2016-01-01') as int) )  +  IF(day('2017-01-22')  > day('2016-01-01'), 1, 0 )
```

With out day consideration

```
select (cast(year('2017-01-22') as int) - cast(year('2016-01-01') as int) )*12 +  (cast(month('2017-01-22') as int) - cast(month('2016-01-01') as int) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get difference between two dates in month through simple logic

```
month(DATE(from_utc_timestamp(date2, 'IST'))) - month(DATE(from_utc_timestamp(date1, 'IST')))
```

Comment: This will not consider the year factor
Suppose date1 = 2020-09-01 and date2 = 2021-11-01
your answer will be 2 instead of 14